# Computing $g'(3)$ given $g(x) = xf(x)/(x^3+5),\, f(3),\, f'(3)$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Given the function $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $g(x)=\frac{xf(x)}{x^3+5}$, my task is to find derivative of function g at $x=3$ where $f(3) = -1,f'(3) = 4$. Should I substitute in the value $3$ before finding the derivative or get the general form and then substitute in the value of $x$?

Comment: First differentiate and then put $x=3$

Comment: For stack community, these kind of questions might seem silly, but they are really important for students who are learning the basics of derivatives. I have seen kids trying to solve $x^2-2x+1=0$ by differentiating both sides, $2x-2=0$, and then saying $x=1$ is a solution of the equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know about $f(3)=-1,f'(3)=4$and $g(x)=\frac {xf(x)}{x^3+5}\to g'(3)=?$
$$g'(x)=\\\frac {(xf(x))'\times (x^3+5)-(x^3+5)'\times(xf(x))}{(x^3+5)^2}=\\\frac {(1f(x)+xf'(x))\times (x^3+5)-(3x^2+0)\times(xf(x))}{(x^3+5)^2}$$then put $x=3$ and you willl have
$$g'(3)=\\\frac {(1f(3)+3f'(3))\times (3^3+5)-(3(3)^2+0)\times(3f(3))}{(3^3+5)^2}=\\\frac {(-1+3(4))\times (27+5)-(27+0)\times(3(-1))}{(27+5)^2}$$

Comment: Is computing g'(3) before finding g'(x) bring up an error? (())′ The leading x is would be treated as a placeholder for 3 and the derivative of 3 would be 0? So we must always find the general form before substitution?

Comment: As a hint:find f'(1) if   f(x)=x^2  before finding f'(x)=2x,can you do it ?

Comment: If you put the number in the function, there will be a number and derivative is zero .